# Checkbox to modify textbox in Word 2010 

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to have a MS Word 2010 document where there is a checkbox (ckeckable) and a textbox (textfield) where different text is displayed depending on whether the checkbox is clicked or not.

I have tried searching for it but somehow all the suggestions are not meant as solutions for the checkbox question...

I would think that the solution should be used in Visual Basic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        TextBox1.Text = "Checked!"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "Unchecked."
    End If
End Sub
```

This assumes you have a checkbox called `CheckBox1` and a text box called `TextBox1`. The above code goes in the ThisDocument module.

Result looks like this [image] and this [image].

**EDIT** Whoops, I made these pics in Excel... Oh well, they look almost identical in Word.

**EDIT** You have now changed the requirement and want the textbox to "be hidden" when the checkbox is unchecked. There is no formal way to "hide" a textbox, but you can remove it visible features, i.e. the text it contains as well as the "sunken" special effect, such that it is indistinguishable from its background:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        TextBox1.Text = "Checked!"
        TextBox1.SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectSunken
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox1.SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectFlat
        'Textbox is now "invisible"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, something like that, But when I want to print it, the box is still leaving a gap of empty space on the paper - could it be solved with a "hidden box when not active?" or something like that?

Comment: Just tested it and it prints fine for me... Does the checkbox print? BTW If you find this answer useful, then please remember to accept it by clicking the checkmark to its left.

Comment: Hi Jean, Francis, I would like the textbox to be hidden when the checkbox is not marked and visible when it is checked, do you know how to do that? If so, I would be more than happy to answered botton :-)

Comment: I have now edited my answer to reflect this new requirement, but in the future please avoid pulling this kind of bait-and-switch. If the answer answers your question, then accept it. If you have a new question, then ask a new question. People will help.

Comment: I have posted another question - I'm sure you know the answer to that one as well.....