# Checkbox to modify textbox in Word 2010 - part II

Tags: vba, ms-word

Ok so maybe I didn't ask my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224615/checkbox-to-modify-textbox-in-word-2010) correctly - it was about hiding a textbox when the checkbox was not acitve... Sorry for the 'misformulating' of the question.

I would like to hide the text in the soecific textbox (and the textbox) when the checkbox is not active and not just the textbox.

Comment: What do you mean by "checkbox not active"? Do you mean "unchecked"? What do you mean by "hide the text in the soecific textbox (and the textbox)"? How did the answer to [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224615/checkbox-to-modify-textbox-in-word-2010) not do this? Please formulate your question such that someone who starts with no knowledge of your situation can understand it. Right now it's a mystery to everyone.

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm making this much more difficult than it is (and therefore hard to understand)...

I want to have a checkbox where I can check it and then a textbox becomes visible (not hidden text) along with text inside the textbox. When the checkbox is checked again (meaning unchecked) then the textbox ALONG with the text inside the textbox should be hidden text, not just white... When the text (and textbox) is hidden, it will not be printed out (which is the point of the 'task')...

I hope that this clearyfied the question somewhat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few ideas that you can work into [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9227892/119775) to your previous question:

```
TextBox1.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 255) ' "hide" the text by making it white
TextBox1.ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' "unhide" the text by making it black

TextBox1.Text = "" ' remove the text entirely

TextBox1.SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectFlat ' "hide" the empty textbox 
' by making it blend in with the page background
```

If you want different answers, then you will have to clarify your question.

**EDIT** You are looking for something that does not exist. You want to "*make the 'content' of the textbox 'hidden text' so that it's not visible (and therefore will not print)*". There is no such thing as "hidden text", but in the code above and in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9227892/119775) to your previous question, you got a couple of ideas for good workarounds that do what you want: whitening or removing the text, and removing special effects on the textbox.  These things *will* make the textbox (and/or the text it contains) not visible such that it does not print. I have tested this.

Need proof? I've printed to a to PDF just to show you. Below are snapshots of the results. 
I'm not sure what more you expect!

[image] Uncheck the checkbox and the textbox becomes invisible: [image]

Comment: Ok, thank you - well that was why I asked. I couldn't find the answer to it elsewhere.